# Python social auth and drf social oauth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I need help of community.

In my Django project with django-rest-framework, we use JWT authentication and want to implement the social login by google. So, I installed and configured drf-social-oauth2 with backend google-oath2 in the project as shown in docs.

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "social_django",
    "oauth2_provider",
    "drf_social_oauth2",
    ...
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                ...
            ],
        },
    }
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        "oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication",
        "drf_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication",
    ),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "drf_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2",
    "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2",
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_REQUIRE_POST = True
ACTIVATE_JWT = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
]


SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = env(
    "SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY", default="SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY"
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = env(
    "SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET", default="SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET"
)
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("", include("social_django.urls", namespace="social")),
    path("auth/", include("drf_social_oauth2.urls", namespace="drf")),
]
```

**And now the question itself.**
How to implement redirection with the necessary data after user authorization on an external resource?

I have a user's entry point with a redirect to google authorization

```py
    path(
        "sign_in/google",
        views.AuthViewSet.as_view({"post": "sign_in_google"}),
        name="sign_in_google",
    ),
```

method

```py
    @extend_schema(request=None, responses={302: None})
    def sign_in_google(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        strategy = load_strategy(request)
        backend = load_backend(
            strategy=strategy,
            name="google-oauth2",
            redirect_uri=f"{self.request.scheme}://{self.request.get_host()}/complete/google-oauth2/",
        )
        return do_auth(backend, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)
```

And if I follow as per our requirements we need the user to redirect to google-oauth2 page and login with credentials and also our app to access data and create user. This achieved by
`http://localhost:8000/sign_in/google` API it redirect to `http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/` with necessary parameters and social user with django user created and redirect to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL with session authentication.
This part is working and user is created successfully.

Redirection is working fine. Reverse redirection with user creation works fine too. But how do I send data to the api in the documentation to get an authorization token on the server? (We do not have session authorization).

Please need your help to understand the process, I read a lot and watched tutorials but didn't get as expected.

If you need any detail please ask.